# How to keep spaces within angle brackets of C++ casting operators in Visual C++ 2015?

Tags: casting, code-formatting, visual-c++-2015

I want to format my C++ casting operators this way:

```cpp
Class * foo = static_cast< Class * >( bar );
```

Visual Studio insists on removing the spaces within the angle brackets:

```cpp
Class * foo = static_cast<Class*>( bar );
```

How do I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 5):

Go to *Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > Spacing*, and check the (wrongly named) *Insert space within parentheses of a C-style cast* box. For some reason, it also applies to the angle brackets of C++ casting operators.

[image: Where's the damn setting?]