# Visual Studio C# : How to keep spaces between angle brackets?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, code-formatting

Currently when I hit ; at the end of a line such as:

```
Rigidbody targetRigidbody = colliders[ i ].GetComponent< Rigidbody >();
```

Visual Studio 2017 automatically converts this into:

```
Rigidbody targetRigidbody = colliders[ i ].GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

I want to keep empty spaces between angle brackets as that is the way I've been writing code for the last 6 years. C++ has this (albeit [wrongly named](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45821470/4495751) ).
Also if there was a way to make it so that after typing ; VS2017 would add spaces automatically even though I didn't type them, it would be even better!

Answer (score -1):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > [Language] > Formatting > Spacing > Set spacing for method declarations > Insert space between method name and its opening parenthesis